# Error converting value "null" to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]'

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON Object which contains a `null` as string ,which cannot be avoided , when i'm sending this object to my API , im getting this error saying

> Error converting value "null" to type
>   'System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]'

**My Sample JSON**

```
{ 
  Name:'Test',
  Id:'null'
}
```

**My Model / DTO**

```
class Class1{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public long? Id {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: In your json object, `'null'` is a string.

Comment: How will values be populated in the JSON? Will numerics also have quotes wrapped around them, or only null?

Comment: yes it contains string Numeric like '1' or '2' @ColinM

Comment: Are you using JSON.NET or System.Text.Json for serializing/deserializing?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using a `JsonConverter` to handle the logic of parsing the `string` as a `long?` which can be null.

First example using Newtonsoft.Json

```cs
public class NewtonsoftStringToLongJsonConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = (string)reader.Value;
        if (string.Equals("null", value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (!long.TryParse(value, out var parsedValue))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return parsedValue;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Your model updates to

```cs
public class Class1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(NewtonsoftStringToLongJsonConverter))]
    public long? Id { get; set; }
}
```

The second option using the System.Text.Json implementation.

```cs
public class SystemTextStringToLongJsonConverter : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<long?>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
        => typeToConvert == typeof(long?);

    public override long? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var value = reader.GetString();
        if(string.Equals("null", value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return null;
        }

        if(!long.TryParse(value, out var parsedValue))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return parsedValue;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, long? value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Finally, your model updates to

```cs
public class Class1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(NewtonsoftStringToLongJsonConverter))]
    public long? Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: that cannot be avoided , which i have already mentioned in my question , any how thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @ANRUpgradedVersion I've updated my answer based on your criteria, I'll apologize for skimming over the question.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion i appreciate it truly but I was looking for a solution which solves across the models/ DTO's , whereas this need to be implemented on all null able long properties and  on all the classes in each API Model, which is a problem to accept it. @ColinM

Comment: @ANRUpgradedVersion With Newtonsoft (which I assume you're using) you can also add converters to the serializer via [`JsonSerializerSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm#Converters) which will skip the need for applying the attribute to the model. Please update your question also with _**all**_ of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Get the json string. Do `string.Replace("'null'", "null")` then map it to your `dto`